# Maximum Query String Length in Oracle Turing Machines

Tags: turing-machines, oracle-machines

I am learning oracle Turing machines, which is normal Turing machines equipped with a write-only query tape and with access to a query oracle.

My question is, is there a limit of the content that can be written on the query tape?

Here is my try: Suppose the oracle Turing machine is $S(n)$ space-bounded. Then the machine either stop within $2^{O(S(n))}$ steps or loops forever. At each step, the machine can write one symbol to the query tape. So the length of the query content is either no more than $2^{O(S(n))}$ or infinity. (For time-bounded oracle Turing machines, it is trivial.)

I think it is the case, but I am not sure. Also, I couldn't find any information about the size of the query content. Am I correct?

The model I use is similar to the one defined in the book *Computational Complexity: A modern approach*, namely,

> (Oracle Turing Machines) An *oracle* Turing machine is a TM $M$ that has a special write-only tape we call $M$’s *oracle tape* and three special states $q_{query},q_{yes},q_{no}$. To execute $M$, we specify in addition to the input a language $O \subseteq \{0,1\}^∗$ that is used as the oracle for $M$. Whenever during the execution $M$ enters the state $q_{query}$, the machine moves into the state $q_{yes}$ if $q \in O$ and $q_{no}$ if $q \notin O$, where $q$ denotes the contents of the special oracle tape. After the query, the query tape initialised to a blank tape. Note that, regardless of the choice of $O$, a membership query to $O$ counts only as a single computational step. If $M$ is an oracle machine, $O \subseteq \{0, 1\}^∗$ a language, and $x \in \{0,1\}^∗$, then we denote the output of $M$ on input $x$ and with oracle $O$ by $M^O(x)$.

Comment: The answer depends on the exact model. Can you explain your model in more detail?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thank you for the comment. I have updated the question:-)

Comment: How do you measure the space consumption of the machine?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Space assumption is the total number of cells scanned during the computation of work tapes (excluding the query tape).

Comment: In that case, you seem to be correct.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Thanks!